# How to calculate the viewing cone radius (ie. size of a pixel) at a distance in raymarching?

Tags: 3d, glsl, antialiasing, raytracing, raycasting

I'm "raymarching distance fields" (proper lingo: sphere-tracing) in GLSL. To implement cone-marching atop of it (and also to minimize the number of raymarching steps regardless of whether cone-marching is added or not), I need to estimate the radius of the ray cone at any given distance.

Recall with raymarching distance fields, a "hit" is recorded when the distance to an object is smaller than a threshold value, often in code named nearLimit or epsilon. This threshold can be seen as equivalent to the ray-cone radius if we increase it exponentially with distance traveled -- this way, we don't shoot straight thin ray lines into space but cones expanding in accordance with perspective projection. This more accurately covers catching the "right" distant objects (at this point let's ignore the issue of blending materials and filtering normals of *all* intersected objects in the viewing cone at distance t for now...).

At step 0, this radius can be approximated by something such as

```
float fInitialRadius = 1 / min(screenwidth, screenheight);
```

This can then be increased at each step exponentially by applying the starting radius to the distance:

```
fNearLimit = fTotalDist * fInitialRadius;  // after each raymarching step
```

This works OK but still has artifacts. If I use fInitialRadius*fInitialRadius (resulting in a smaller number since initial radius for a 640px framebuffer and a unit-width view-plane is 1/640) I get less artifacts and a more accurate result. But both approaches are inaccurate, the first is too eager (increases radius too much too early), the latter too lazy (increases radius too little too late).

The most accurate factor to increase fNearLimit / the cone radius at a given distance must most likely take into account my current field of view and will vary depending on whether field-of-view is 45° or 60° or 90° or...

**TL;DR**: I want to know **what's the proper calculation or most acceptable approximation of the cone radius at a given distance** given the initial pixel radius at step 0 and the field of view angle?

Comment: I would note that the pixel is typically a square, indeed the cone should be a frustrum. Then, the size is linear in relation of then distance, not exponential.

Comment: Thanks Luca, good point! Let's simplify things a bit.

To implement cone-marching atop of raymarching/sphere-tracing, I would need to at least approximate a "suitable radius" that "errs on the safe side" -- what happens here in cone-marching is comparing "the size of the distance sphere" at the current step position to the "current cone width". But...

Comment: ...ignoring the whole radial-cone / pixel-spherical-disc approximation for a moment and considering the rectangular "view frustum". For a view-plane w world units wide and projecting to 320px * 320px screen units, the total width of the frustum at distance t should be t * w * tan(fovRadians * 0.5), correct? (... or times 1/tan ... or div by tan... or div by 1/tan? :)) For fov=90° then the whole tan (or 1/tan etc.) equals 1, so t * w. (width=height for now. Later then take the min of both.)

Comment: So for a given pixel p, the rectangular sub-portion of the entire up-scaled-as-above view frustum at that distance t is t * w / 320. To err on the safe side, my cone circle then needs to fit inside that rectangle but not overlap it, so radius = min(pixelRectInFrustumWidth, pixelRectInFrustumHeight) / 2.

Comment: See any issues with this reasoning? It's tricky to "test this visually" since I'm getting aliasing artifacts one way or the other, mostly at the edges though which makes me think I shouldn't use the "last cone radius recorded" as the normal epsilon... but that's another topic for another day. Right now I'm not entirely sure whether to multiple or divide by either the tan of fov/2, or the 1/tan of it.

Answer (score 3):

The radius of a cone corresponds linearly to the distance from its tip.  (Otherwise it's not a cone!)

So if your cone has `initialRadius` when it intersects the screen plane, then later:

```
radius(distance) = distance * initialRadius / focalDistance
```

You'll have to recalculate that value at every step, because each step takes you a different distance.

Here `distance` is the distance of the ray from the camera, and `focalDistance` is the distance of the screen plane from the camera.

(For pixels not in the centre of the screen, instead of `focalDistance` it may be more accurate to use the distance of the pixel on the screen plane from the camera.)

(Or perhaps better, don't use *distances* at all.  Just use *depths* instead, i.e. only the component of the vector perpendicular to the screen plane.  This may be your z-axis or your y-axis if you have rotated the scene into the camera frame.)